# ERROR: All flavors must now belong to a named flavor dimension

Tags: android, android-studio, android-productflavors

[Screenshot from Android my build.gradle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YNvFb.png)

It's my first encounter with flavor dimensions. I am trying to compile a ready-made code but somehow I ended up with this issue.

ERROR:

> All flavors must now belong to a named flavor dimension. Learn more at
>   https://d.android.com/r/tools/flavorDimensions-missing-error-message.html
>   Affected Modules: app

I am sorry for being a noob and really don't know how to solve this. If someone had a solution please help me with this.

How to fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [Android documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants?utm_source=android-studio#product-flavors).

> All flavors must belong to a named flavor dimension, which is a group
>   of product flavors. You must assign all flavors to a flavor dimension;
>   otherwise, you will get the build error shown below. **If a given module
>   specifies only one flavor dimension, the Android Gradle plugin
>   automatically assigns all of the module's flavors to that dimension**.

So if you don't care about having different flavor dimension naming you can specify one inside your `module` and it will be applied to all `flavors`like below.

```
android { 
    ...
    flavorDimensions "default"
    ...
}
```

And if you care about different naming you can go with this approach:

```
android {
...
flavorDimensions "default"
...
}


 productFlavors {
            inmemory {
                ...
                dimension "DIM_NAME"
            }
            live {
                ...
                dimension "DIM_NAME_2"
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Answer by @Mohamed Nageh needs an update. At the moment the `flavorDimensions "default"` still works, but this method is marked as deprecated:
[image]

The new way of using flavorDimensions property, and should be as follows:

```
flavorDimensions = ["default"]
```

And if you need several dimensions, you can just extend the array:

```
flavorDimensions = ["default", "alternative", "anotherOne"]
```